# Download file from opensubtitles.org

Tags: c#, file, download

I need to download files from opensubtitles.org trough my application which is written in GTK# and C#. The app is based on .NET 4.0 framework.

At first this was the code I was using:

```
    var tZip = new FastZip();
    try {
        var tRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(tDownloadUrl);
        var tZipResponse = (HttpWebResponse)tRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var tStream = tZipResponse.GetResponseStream()) {
            using (var tMemStream = new MemoryStream()) {
                tStream.CopyTo(tMemStream);
                var tTempPath = Globals.video_location + "OSD";
                Directory.CreateDirectory(tTempPath);
                tZip.ExtractZip(tMemStream, tTempPath, FastZip.Overwrite.Always, null, @"\.srt$", null, false, true);
                var tDirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(tTempPath);
                var tFileInfo = new FileInfo(Globals.location_video);

                var tSrtFile = tDirInfo.EnumerateFiles().FirstOrDefault();
                if (tSrtFile == null) {
                    writeLog("No .srt file found in zip..");
                    goto text;
                }
                writeLog("Downloaded and unpacked: " + tSrtFile.Name);
                File.Copy(tSrtFile.FullName, Globals.video_location+Globals.video_name+".srt", true);
                    Globals.savedTitle = Globals.video_location+Globals.video_name+".srt";
                // clean up..
                Directory.Delete(tTempPath, true);
                writeLog("Deleted temp folder.");
                return true;
            }
        }}
```

And that worked really well up until few days ago, now it is returning a bunch of html code instead of .zip file. I tried even something like this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(link, @"OSD\test.zip");
```

But everything just keeps returning bunch of html code.
The link I am usually trying to download is something like this:
http://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/subad/4287952

If you click on the link above it will just redirect you to the opensubtitles.org page of that particular subtitle. But if you right mouse click on that link and then select "open in new tab" or "open in new window" it will automatically start the download. (Tested in Firefox) 
Also as soon as I paste that link in "Internet Download Manager" application, it will start the download of the zip file automatically.

If you can help me to resolve this problem I will truly be grateful.

Kind Regards.

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML in a browser?  What does it say?  It's probably an error message that could help you understand why the download is failing.  Also you should be checking the `HttpWebResponse`'s `StatusCode` property to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got into this problem because I was filtering the website xml directly. Like from a link such as this one: [opensubtitles.org example](http://www.opensubtitles.org/en/subtitles/4287952/the-walking-dead-days-gone-bye-nl/xml)

And in the beginning it used to work well, but then they changed something on the website and it stopped working. So what I did was build on top of this: [OSHandler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/oshandler/files/v1.1/)

That handler library is using XML-RPC so I believe there won't be any problems in the future.